# Add a custom keybinding with gsettings in ubuntu

Tags: shortcut-keys, gsettings

I can modify existing custom keybindings like this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name "browser"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command "/home/kaiyin/workspace/bash_scripts/focusRun.sh chromium-browser"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding "<Primary><Shift><Alt>b"
```

But how do I add a new one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/597395/how-to-set-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-from-terminal)

Answer (score 8):

Additionally to setting name, command and binding do you also need to change the *custom-keybindings* array assigning all paths you have assigned keybindings too.

The path in your example would be */org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/* and following command would assign this path to the *custom-keybindings* key:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a exaple how to create keyboard shortcut to suspend the system by pressing `<Super> + s` keys:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'systemctl suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Super>s'
```

Comment: Be a little careful with using 'Copy and Paste' answers for questions in AU.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add multiple keybinding like 10 shortcuts, add them like this: then

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom2/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom3/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom4/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom5/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom6/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom7/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom8/','/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom9/']"
```

then add "name" "command" and "binding" for each