# Media Keys not working in Ubuntu 19.10 with Kodi

Tags: 19.10, kodi, media-buttons

I have a NUC set up with Ubuntu 19.10 desktop and try to control it with Harmony Hub over Bluetooth (was the only option that I found in the messy harmony menu). Navigation works well, (even sound control in on the computer which I obviously don't use), but the play pause ffw keys don't. I have tried the playing around with dconf-editor with no luck, and Kodi MPRIS pluggin which just gives error.

Any advice?

I run Kodi disabling Pulse and running through ALSA if that makes any difference.
I moved to Linux on a NUC for my media center experience, since I can setup all media systems on the same computer, (snapclient, chromium, and Kodi) and get a good sound. (Pi4 does not support HD Sound properly, and windows don't support snapclient)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! :-)

Was a gnome feature blocking the keys. Found it after ages of searching ask.ubuntu and trial en error:

- Check the keys with: sudo showkey -k
- Then you need to change the keys in gnome:
- Install the visual key editor: dconf-editor
- Navigate to org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys
- Remove the default values and replace with ['']
- Then you need to change it in one more place:
- Find the keys that you need that have default values: gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys | grep thekey
- Blank the keys with: conf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/thekey "''"
- Check which keys have been set: /etc/systemd/system/cockpit.socket.d/listen.conf
- reboot

[Media Keys not working on Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990284/m...untu-17-10)
[Add a custom keybinding with gsettings in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527990/a...-in-ubuntu)

Comment: If other apps already work with the media keys, does this solution have any side-effects for them?