# Switching between same application windows with scroll wheel on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Dock

Tags: 22.04, ubuntu-dock, gsettings

I searched a lot and couldn't really find an answer how to switch between windows of the ***same*** application in the **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS** Dock ([See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jupZz.jpg)).

ATTEMPT 1

**Configure `gsettings`** (based on answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966887/switching-between-windows-with-scroll-wheel-on-ubuntu-dock)):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

but this causes to cycle windows of not only single application (say, Firefox), but the whole Dock scrolls simultaneously. This results in cycling over all the windows for all applications.

ATTEMPT 2

**Set custom key bindings**
(based on answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527990/add-a-custom-keybinding-with-gsettings-in-ubuntu)):

Thought to set custom key bindings, so that `Ctrl + scroll-action` would cycle through the application windows, and `Ctrl` would normally scroll the Dock. But I got stuck here, as I couldn't figure out the correct commands. I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'ctrl-scroll'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'cycle-windows'    # ?????
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Ctrl><scroll-action>'    #?????
```

Is there a way to achieve switching windows of a single application in the Dock through scrolling, without entire Dock scrolling simultaneously?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension.

Here are the settings:

[image: here are the settings with ss]

Comment: Up vote would be appreciated